# Android : WebView position is wrong

Tags: android, webview, position

I have an app that should display a WebView in full screen but I have a problem:

I have a white bar at the bottom of my screen! I can suppress it when I slide the webview in the bottom but I would like it to be ok without the user action.

Image: 
[image]

Here's my code to instantiate my WebView:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
//webView.setTop(0);
//webView.setLeft(0);
webView.setInitialScale(getScale(act));
webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
webView.loadUrl(INTERNAL_LINK);


private static int getScale(Activity act){
    double widthScreen = (double) 
    MyConnection.getClientHandler().getClientData().getiDefinitionX();

    Display display = ((WindowManager) 
    act.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    int width = display.getWidth();
    Double val = new Double(width)/new Double(widthScreen);
    val = val * 100d;
    return val.intValue();
}
```

When I don't use **getScale** my webview is zoomed, even with `webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
 webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);`

My manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:banner="@drawable/logo"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/logo"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <!--<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />-->
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

My onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.myContext">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="name"
    android:textColor="#FF0000"/>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_chargement"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand you want to show your all contains inside webview with full screen. I don't know  how are you using your webview layout. So I am giving you all possibilities

**1st ---> WebView Inside Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

**2nd ---> By Coding IN Activity**

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // remove title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

**3rd---> Declaring in Manifest**

```
<activity android:name=".ActivityName"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"/>
```

Comment: I tried the second and the third (I already have the first but with a FrameLayout) but it doen't work. My problem is my Webview seems to be in full screen but the initial position begin at -1 and not 0. I will some more of my code in the question

Comment: Are you using FrameLayout ?  Can you post your XML code please ?

Comment: Yeah I use it, not really necessary by the way but didn't see the difference with RelativeLayout or LinearLayout for my case. I posted a lot of my code in the question

Comment: How many views are you using in FramLayout ? One thing you need to remember while using Framelayout is "When adding multiple views to a FrameLayout, each will be stacked on top of the previous one."

Comment: I use a total of 4 view : 1 before the webview and the 2 others after the webview.

Comment: I just tried with a RelativeLayout and I get the same result

Comment: do one thing... I think FrameLayout is problem... I am giving you one smaple xml code.. Please create a new sample_web.xml in layout folder and paste below code

Comment: I am updating my answer

Comment: Got it.. problem is you are defining all views inside FrameLayout... You have to define all these view inside a Layout. Means define a Relative or Linear as per your comfort, and inside this layout, declare FrameLayout.. One sample I am giving you

Comment: <RelativeLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="350dip"
            android:layout_height="350dip" />
    </FrameLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: I tried to do the same (on RelativeLayout at first and then put each of my Views in a FrameLayout)  but I get the same result :/

Comment: I even tried to suppress all my view apart from the webview and put it in a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout but still the same result

Comment: May i know What type output you WANT EXACTLY ?

Comment: Is there any need to use FraneLayout ?

Comment: Nop, I can change with any Layout. But I already tried with a Relative or a Linear and still the same result

Comment: An what type of output ? I just need my WebView in full screen, if it works I can change the rest of my code to match it !

Comment: First initialise Relative layout and use only web-view and set width and height match_parent. then ensure that you are getting exact output what you want. If yes then start adding view on it

Comment: That's my problem, even if I do "match_view" on RelativeView and WebView it still doesn't want to take full screen...